# Quiver and relations of $F\mathrm{SL}(2,q)$

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, computer-algebra, modular-representation-theory

$\DeclareMathOperator\SL{SL}$Let $q=p^n$ be a prime power and $F$ a field of characteristic two.
Let $G=SL(2,q)$ the group of $2 \times 2$ special linear matrices over the field with $q$ elements with determinant 1. $FG$ denotes the group algebra over $F$ (assume $F$ is a splitting field if needed so that the algebra is Morita equivalent to a quiver algebra).

> Question 1: Are general quiver and relations known for $F\SL(2,q)$ (or $F\SL(r,q)$ for $r \geq 2$)? Is there a nice reference?

In particular, how many blocks does $F\SL(r,q)$ have?

> Question 2: In the case $G=SL(2,5)$, is there an elementary proof that the principal block of $FG$ is isomorphic to an algebra of quaternion type $Q(3 \mathcal{A})_2$ (with $k=2$ as in the notation of Erdmann?)?

This should be true according to page 305 in the book " Blocks of Tame Representation Type and Related Algebras" by Erdmann (except that it seems to be not mentioned for which $k \geq 2$ this is true?).

(Is there a computer program that can calculate quiver and relations for this example and more general for finite groups of small order? QPA can only do it when $FG$ is connected for very small $G$.)

edit: With the help of Magma, one can indeed verify that $F\SL(2,5)$ has principal block corrending to $Q(3 \mathcal{A})_2$ with $k=2$. But it would be nice to have an explicit reference for this.

Comment: For question 2, one can also look at https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01456839 proposition 7.6.